# How to have gulp-replace affect only certain files?

Tags: gulp, gulp-replace

I've got this gulp task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('myStaticFiles', function() {
    gulp.src('staticSite/**')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/site'));
});
```

Between `src` and `dest` I want to do a `gulp-replace` (or similar). I currently have:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('myStaticFiles', function() {
    gulp.src('staticSite/**')
        .pipe(replace(/mypattern/, "replacevalue"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/site'));
});
```

However, this affects *all* files in the pipe. I want to:

- have *only certain files* (either a specific file by name, or files with a certain extension) in the stream affected by `replace`; and
- have *all files* reach `gulp.dest`.

How can I do so?

[The `gulp-replace` documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace) has nothing on this, so perhaps I'm just lacking some knowledge on "the gulp way" to do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach, using [gulp-if](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if):

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  var gulp    = require( 'gulp' ),
      gulpif  = require( 'gulp-if' ),
      replace = require( 'gulp-replace' );

  var condition = function ( file ) {
    // TODO: add business logic
    return true;
  }

  gulp.task( 'myStaticFiles', function() {
    return gulp
      .src( 'staticSite/**' )
      .pipe( gulpif( condition, replace( /mypattern/, 'replacevalue' ) ) )
      .pipe( gulp.dest( 'build/site' ) );
  });

})();
```

Comment: Exactly, all you had commented is true :) And with the new info you gave me, I will go for combine this plugin with gulp-if. Actually, its not very elegant, but easy: can't spend more time "debugging for you" :D Will edit my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your new answer state matches my (intended) question. I'll try to verify a bit later if all this works. (PS. I've purged my previous comments as they became obsolete.)